# GKScore doesn't get incremented

Tags: ios, game-center

Why score doesn't get incremented?

```
GKLeaderboard *lb = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] initWithPlayerIDs:@["G:1518137155"]];
  lb.category = @"top_matcher";
  [lb loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
     if(error == nil){
        GKScore *score = [scores lastObject];
        if(score) {
           score.value += 40;
           [score reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"ERR: %@ SC:%lld %@ %@ %d", error, score.value, score.playerID, score.category, scores.count);
           }];
        }
     }
  }];
```

I see no error in output

> ERR: (null) SC:61 G:1689523782 top_matcher 1

Comment: Is the player id you are asking the leaderboard about the local player?

Comment: No, Player id is not local player id. It works for local playerId

Comment: I don't think you can change the score for a player other than the local (authenticated) player.

Comment: I feel the same, but there is no clear documentation on this. Not sure what is the best way to update score of some other game user.

Comment: Why do you need to update the other player's score?

Comment: User creates a puzzle and anyone can play that puzzle. When someone likes the puzzle, the user who created the puzzle should get coins or points

Comment: I think you'll need to make a custom backend to handle that sort of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6).

> Almost all classes in Game Kit that send data to or retrieve information from Game Center expect the device to have an authenticated local player. The work those classes do is always on behalf of the local player. For example, if your game reports scores to a leaderboard, it can only report a score earned by the local player.